# how to set a relative margin-top for children components under Appbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, styling, material-ui

I'm using material-ui Appbar and have fixed it to the top of the React app with high z-index in my Main component. however, all my children components are using display-flex. I want avoid any children being obstructed by the app bar. I tried setting a margin-top for all my children components Div but since the app bar resizes accordance to orientation and screen size, I can set a fixed margin-top. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions to this are explained in [the docs](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#fixed-placement). One of them is to render an empty toolbar right after the appbar:

```
<AppBar position="fixed">
    <Toolbar>{/* content */}</Toolbar>
</AppBar>
<Toolbar />
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem doesn't seem to be react related, at least at this point in time
id say it's CSS related.

if I understand you have something like this

```
<body>
<div class="fixed-to-top"></div>
<div class="react-root"></div>
</body>
```

Why don't you set ur appbar to have the following:

```
.fixed-to-top{
   position:relative; 
   top:0;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

and add the above css to your css so that your appbar would stay always on top but won't obscure other elements below

let me know if this makes sense

Comment: Mike , with the above css properties, my app bar would move if i scroll the page, I want it fixed at the top.

Comment: The first render of children components should render right below the app bar. later when i scroll the content the children content should be allowed to scroll under the appbar

Comment: how about putting all your scrollable content inside the bottom div. I mean, on top level 2 divs, one is appbar and the bottom one is a container for all other stuff.  then just do overflow:scroll

Comment: little unclear, anytime I change the appbar position to anything but fixed, the app bar moves on scroll.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle, this is what I mean. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelrodov/3dwwgj93/3/)

Comment: if i make the jsfiddle output container small another scroll bar appears on the outside that moves the appbar. Take a look at his app, this is the behavior I'm looking for. https://paulhoughton.github.io/remember/ Ty it in chrome mobile view with added items

Comment: jsfiddle does not show the completely correct picture, since the html that we generate sits inside another component, over which you have no control. but in your own page you can set: overflow-y:hidden in order not to have scrolls. Also take a look at flex-grow: 0 on the ttle bar, meaning that it won't grow and flex:5 on the bottom parent meaning that it will grow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124032/discussion-between-mike-rodov-and-jasan).